# Calculate average from a list of data

Tags: haskell, filter, average

I have a list reviews and that list is filled with:

```
    data Review = Review artist::String score::Integer Tour String String Locatie [String]
```

So what I'm trying to do is to calculate the average score of the reviews from a specific artist. What I have so far is a function to filter also the reviews of a artist like so:

```
    filterByArtiest :: String -> [Review] -> [Review]
    filterByArtiest art = filter (\a -> artiest a == art)
```

And this is what I had in mind to calculate the average:

```
    gem :: String -> (String -> [Review] -> [Review]) -> Double
    gem art =
```

But I have like no idea how to finish that function to calculate the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is simple:

- Filter out that particular artist that you are interested at.
- Extract (map) all the score of that particular artist.
- Calculate his average by the list of scores obtained for that artist.

Assuming that your Review record is something like this:

```
data Review = Review {
     artist::String,
     score::Integer,
     tour :: String ,
     locatie :: [String] 
    }
```

You can calculate the average using this function:

```
average :: String -> [Review] -> Double
average artistName reviews = fromIntegral (sum scores) / fromIntegral (length scores)
    where artists = filterByArtiest artistName reviews
          scores = map score artists
```

Comment: You get a better average function, if you write it as a right-fold: `avg = uncurry (/) . foldr (\x (s,n) -> (s+x, n+1)) (0, 0)`. It may matter if you have a long list, and don't want to keep it entirely in memory and walking it twice.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to filter your list to get just the reviews for a partticular artist. If your list of reviews is called `reviews`, then something like this should work:

```
joesReviews = filter (\review -> artist review == "Joe Bloggs") reviews
```

Next, extract all of the scores into a list.

```
scores = map score joesReviews
```

Now you can use `sum scores` to determine the total score. Then use `length scores` to calculate the number of values. Now you have everything you need to calculate the average.

Comment: And then how do I declare that scores function? scores :: Map.Map -> [score]?